# Researching German soldiers who were prisoners of war in US during WWII?

Tags: united-states, military-records, world-war-2, imprisonment

My father-in-law was in the Latvian army then conscripted into the German army. We believe he was captured by American forces in either North Africa or Italy and brought to the US.  He was in a camp along the East Coast or New England area.  I have contacted both WASt and ICRC who have no records on him.  Where do I look next to find out where he was held and when he was repatriated?

Comment: have you tried the National Archives https://aad.archives.gov/aad/series-description.jsp?s=644&cat=WR26&bc=,sl

Comment: What records do you actually have?